# What is the location of the data part of a parameter?

Tags: go-ethereum, raw-transaction

In this doc :

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI

Given this representation of the contract

```
contract Foo {
  function bar(fixed[2] xy) {}
  function baz(uint32 x, bool y) returns (bool r) { r = x > 32 || y; }
  function sam(bytes name, bool z, uint[] data) {}
}
```

it is said that If we wanted to call the method sam with the arguments "dave", true and [1,2,3] it would be broken down into :

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060: the location of the data part of the first parameter (dynamic type), measured in bytes from the start of the arguments block. In this case, 0x60.
```

What does that mean ?

I can't wrap my head around this concept nor the way it's ordered (methodid,datalocationparam1,hexparm2,datalocationparam3,hexparam3,hexparam1,datalocationparam3,entry1,entry2,entry3),or what an "entry" is.

Comment: I struggled mightily with this exact issue. I don't know if there's a better solution, but I can tell you that if you pick apart the page you've referenced above, what you're looking for is in there.

It took me a couple of days, but I was able to ultimately figure it out using what's there. It's not at all clearly written, though.

Comment: did you ever figured out to ordering ? (methodid,datalocationparam1,hexparm2,datalocationparam3,hexparam3,hexparam1,datalocationparam3,hex3-1,hex3-2,hex3-3)

Comment: I did. There's a GitHub repository called "ethslurp" that does this, but it's kind of hacky. In a file called transaction.cpp. In a function called parseParams. The function takes the input string and a list of parameter types and returns and returns the parameters in a pipe separated string. It's hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party here, but my understanding is this:

First part of the data:

0. MethodID (4 bytes / 8 hex characters)
1. location_of_dynamic_parameter_1 (32 bytes / 64 character)
2. binary_parameter (32 bytes / 64 characters)
3. location_of_dynamic_parameter_3 (32 bytes / 64 characters)

The location of dynamic parameters is the hex value of the number of bytes after the method id.

In this case the first dynamic parameter is immediately after the data above. So 32 bytes + 32 bytes + 32 bytes = 96 bytes which when we convert to hex is 0x60

The dynamic parameters start with 32 bytes to describe the length. This is 4 for bytes because there are 4 bytes in "dave".

After this is the actual content of the first dynamic parameter. For "dave" this turns into the UTF-8/ASCII encoding padded right to 32 bytes.

Next is the start of the 3rd dynamic parameter. The location of this is:
32 Bytes (P1 location) + 32 Bytes (Bool) + 32 Bytes (P3 location) + 32 Bytes (P1 Length) + 32 Bytes (P1 Content) = 160 Bytes (A0 in hex).

Again for the dynamic parameters they start with the length, for a `uint256[]` this is how many items are in the array. In this case they are saying 3 items in the array.

And finally is 3x 32 bytes for each of the items in that array